# Listview em outra Activity

Tags: java, android, listview

Eu tenho uma `Listview` em minha `activity` principal quando eu clico em um botão, ele adiciona dados na minha `Listview`, até ai tudo correto.

Como eu faço para mostrar essa `listview` em outra `activity`? Eu mostro outros dados (`EditText`) sem problemas, mas `listview` eu não consegui.

Tentei usar para enviar os dados :

```
 public void EnviarParaResultadoActivity(View view){

    EditText resultadoID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.resultadoID);
    EditText nomesorteioID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nomesorteioID);
    ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Bundle parametro = new Bundle();

    parametro.putString("resultadoID", resultadoID.getText().toString());
    parametro.putString("nomesorteioID", nomesorteioID.getText().toString());
    parametro.putString("listView1", listView1.getContext().toString());

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,   ResultadoActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(parametro);

    startActivity(intent);      
}
```

e para receber os dados:

```
public void ReceberParametros() {       

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent != null){         
            Bundle parametros = intent.getExtras();
            if(parametros != null){             
              String resultadoID = parametros.getString("resultadoID");
              String nomesorteioID = parametros.getString("nomesorteioID");
              String listview1 = parametros.getString("listview1");

              TextView ResultadoTV =   (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultadoID); 
              TextView NomesorteioTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nomesorteioID); 
              ListView listviewLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);    


              ResultadoTV.setText(" "+resultadoID);
              NomesorteioTV.setText(" "+nomesorteioID);
              listviewLV.setFilterText(" "+listview1);

            }
        }
    }
```

Os dados da `TextView` São exibidos normalmente, mas do `Listview` não. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar os dados o correto é setar os valores numa classe (model) e enviar com o `putExtra()`:

```
Intent it = new Intent(this, ResultadoActivity.class);
it.putExtra("objeto", classModel);
startActivity(it);
```

E para pegar:

```
ClassModel cm = (ClassModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("objeto");
```

E o `ClassModel` deve ter `implements Serializable`:

```
public class ClassModel implements Serializable {
    //Código...
}
```

Para setar os dados na `ListView`:

```
ArrayList<ClassModel> array = cm.getArray(); //cm.getArray deve conter o array de dados que vão ser setados no listView
ArrayAdapter<ClassModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(SegundaActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
listview1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Como eu faço isso? Desculpe, sou iniciante e não entendi direito

Comment: Sabe o que é `MVC`?

Comment: Sei sim, model, view, controller

Comment: Bom, quando você quer passar vários dados entre activitys, em vez de mandar várias String, int, boolean..., você pode setar todos os dados numa classe model e enviar essa classe(a instancia dela), basicamente tu cria uma nova instância `Classe c - new Classe();`, seta os valores que deseja passar com set e envia com `Intent.puExtra()`, e acredito que o modo como você está setando o seu listview está errado